# Android App with a database crashes

Tags: android, installation, sqlite

I've built an android application with a database (sqlite 3) targeted for Android 2.2 with API level 8. It works by copying the database from the assets directory to the /data/data/com.myapp.db/databases folder. It works just fine on the emulator. However, when I try to install the application on HTC mobile device with version 2.2 and 2.1-update1, it crashes. The error says "Failed to Copy the Database". Could this be as a result of the database path that I used on the emulator and the actual device mismatching? I'm eagerly looking for your answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of permissions. The application has limited access to the system folder, unless you have your device rooted. The database you create from your application is saved under application directory. Maybe i didn't properly understand your issue, but... you are not creating a new database, but just moving a database you have in your assets to a final directory?. Where does this database in assets come from?. Why don't you create your tables in the Android application?